# HTTPS Link Wrapping Regex

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression which matches all `http://` links

`(http:\/\/[a-z0-9\.\/]+)/i`

How do i modify it to include `https://` links?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to  add `s` after the string `http` and also add `?` after `s` to make it optional

```
/(https?:\/\/[a-z0-9\.\/]+)/i
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
https?:\/\/[a-z0-9\.\/]+
```